# Platforms for EOS research

Tags: resources

Hello everyone is there a place where the community discusses relevant research for the advancement of EOS? Is there any community driven research like in Ethereum?

Thanks and greetings :)

Comment: https://eosmechanics.com/ is one

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for EOS development discussion, following telegram group might be of interest to you:

https://t.me/joinchat/Esi1OkPktgcFeJ3Lmlcrqg

However, I don't know of pure "research" resources outside Block.one.